# IBM Cloud: How to open Analytics Engine port 7070?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, ibm-cloud, kylin, analytics-engine

I want to use big data services on the IBM Cloud, so I found Analytics Engine(AE) and BigInsight, but unfortunately, BigInsight is going to stop, so I can only choose AE. However, IBM AE is different AWS and GCP big data services, AE prohibits users from having root permissions, so I cannot change some configurations on the clusters, but **I want to install Kylin on the cluster, and I need to open Kylin's 7070 port**, later, I found that Knox can map ports, but it looks like IBM  change it. **So how do I open port 7070 for external access? Can I get root permissions? Or is there any other big data service besides "Analytic Engine" and "BigInsight"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Analytics Engine service on IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine?topic=AnalyticsEngine-IAE-overview) can be customized and additional services and packages installed. However, [there are restrictions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine?topic=AnalyticsEngine-cust-cluster#what-can-you-customize-). As you pointed out, it includes that you cannot have root permissions and open ports for security reasons.

To be entirely flexible and have root permissions you could deploy a Hadoop cluster to a Kubernetes or OpenShift cluster or run it on virtual machines.